# Finagle + Thrift: Count method invocations

Tags: scala, thrift, finagle, zipkin

I’m working on a system of microservices, implemented in Scala with Finagle and Thrift as the platform.

As there are a few services that nobody touched for a while, I need to find out if they are used at all anymore (or rather, which parts are not used anymore). For that, IMHO a simple invocation count for each method would suffice (since the service was started, or possibly in the last 24h).

As far as I see, the Finagle/Thrift integration does not bring something like this built-in, at least not exposed in the admin panel. So what would be the most clever way to do this? Just add a filter that counts the invocations and exposes them via the admin interface? Or would Zipkin (possibly with custom code) help here?

Comment: `grep method log.txt  | wc -l`

Comment: Unfortunately that’s impossible here as there is no log to disc, only to Graylog, and that information does not end up there. However, for regular setups, this will work.

Comment: Two step solution then: 1. Add logging. 2. Search Graylog. Alternatively: 1. Add logging to disk, 2. See previous comment

Comment: I don't know about 2016, but Finagle does now have per-method stats filters I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Some people use zipkin to identify dead services, but probably metrics/stats would be the better route if you are trying to break down and report by thrift method.